# Using slick to create a carousel from li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using slick to create a carousel from list items
The structure of list is like this

```
<div class="slicker">
    <li>
        <img />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img />
    </li>
</div>
```

I'm unable to create a carousel of it .
The content rather appears as a normal list.
When checking the node I see the relevant classed added to the dom.

Link for slick :https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Have you called $(".slicker").slick(); in your js?

Comment: Would be helpful if you shared your HTML markup and JS. Anyways make sure you have placed the **/slick** folder in your project and added references to **slick.css** and **slick.js** files on your HTML file. Also make sure you have invoked $(".slicker").slick()

Comment: So I'm able to run it now, the problem now is that on a page it allows to display 2 item 
 ' [Item1]    [Item 2]...
[Item(n-1)][Item(n)]' 
And 1st and n-1 are getting displayed on 1st page itself

Comment: You shouldn't put ```<li>``` in ```<div>``` in the first place. As [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li] says:
**An <ul>, <ol> or <menu> element. Though not a non-conforming usage, the obsolete <dir> may also be a parent.**

Answer (score 30):

Actually, Slick use div element as slide by default, but you can change it with the "slide" parameter (slide     | element | 'div' | Element query to use as slide).

In your case you need to have (in your js) something like:

```
$('.slicker').slick({
  slide: 'li'
});
```

You can also change your code with 'div' like "v2solutions.com" said but this change your semantics.

Comment: Solved my problems..who is waiting to accept this answer?

Comment: It should be noted that this parameter produces a somewhat invalid DOM structure, which may or may not be an issue. There was some discussion on github a while back, but as far as I can tell, the issue has not been addressed, even though there have been suggested fixes. https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/212

Answer (score -3):

Could you please try <div> instead of <li>. slick seems to be working with `<div>` only.

Comment: You can dun it with div as well just need to mention that you need to slide li
slide: 'li'