# how to add slick slider on ul li elements

Tags: slick.js

I want to add slick slider on ul elements but not getting how to do that. Below is my html

```js
jQuery(".post-list-new").slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 1280,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll:
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: "unslick"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<ul class="post-list-new clearfix">
  <li class="post-holder-new post-holder-new-17">
    <div clas="my_image">
      img 1 here
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="post-holder-new post-holder-new-17">
    <div clas="my_image">
      img 1 here
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="post-holder-new post-holder-new-17">
    <div clas="my_image">
      img 1 here
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Anyone have idea what is wrong in this then please let me know

Comment: You have a syntax error near `breakpoint: 1280, ... slidesToScroll: ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using slick to create a carousel from li elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056855/using-slick-to-create-a-carousel-from-li-elements)

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys is it possible

I'm using Slick slider

I have 5 post and per row display 3 post but i want next slide active only 2 post

Like: post 1, 2, 3, In the first slide then next slide show only 4, 5.

```
 <script>
$('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    responsive: [
        {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
        }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
        }
        },
        {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Slick slider code on ul li elements

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  display:none;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul.slick-dots {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
ul.slick-dots li {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
}
ul.slick-dots li.slick-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="slide_main">
<ul class="Pre_slide">
  <li class="post-holder-new post-holder-new-17">
    <div clas="my_image">
      img 1 here
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="post-holder-new post-holder-new-17">
    <div clas="my_image">
      img 1 here
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="post-holder-new post-holder-new-17">
    <div clas="my_image">
      img 1 here
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="post-holder-new post-holder-new-17">
    <div clas="my_image">
      img 1 here
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
    $('.Pre_slide').slick({
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      arrows:true,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      nextArrow:$('.slider-next'),
      prevArrow:$('.slider-prev'),
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true

          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality. Without sufficient explaination, your answer is hard to understand.
If the OP can't understand your answer, then he also won't be able to reproduce your possible solution. As such it 
would be worthless to him/her. Please add a sufficient explaination of your possible solution.

Comment: I have write full code above and how can i explain full code line by  line

Comment: And if anyone need help regarding this code I will explain in detail